# Почему не объединяются датафреймы внутри цикла?

Tags: python, pandas

Для простоты - есть два датафрейма пандаса, которые легко объединяются между собой методом merge. Но если эти данные лежат в списке, то при его итерации не получается объединить датафреймы (в реалной задаче есть большой список схожих датафреймов):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что merge возвращает новый датафрейм, а не изменяет существующий?

Comment: Код и данные в вопросе должны быть в текстовом виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `.merge()` *не изменяет датафрейм*, на который вы его применили, только *возвращает новый датафрейм*.

Чтобы сохранить этот новый датафрейм, нужно его присвоить какой-нибудь переменной:

```
df_merged = con.merge(...)
```

Так как вы это не сделали, вы его просто выкинули.

Результат вашей последней команды

```
x.merge(y, how='outer')
```

т.к. она является последней (единой) в клетке Jupyter ноутбука, изобразится (и потом тоже уничтожится).

Между прочим, в цикле

```
for i in a_list:
```

вы пытаетесь сначала сделать `x.merge(x, ...)` (потому что `x` является первым элементом списка `a_list`) - что вы явно не хотите.

Comment: спасибо! совсем забыл об этом

Comment: @moby2k, не стоит, это повторяющаяся ошибка нас всех. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Как это сделать правильно?

```
a_list = [x, y, z, ...]   # сколько нужно
result = a_list[0]        # первый


for i in a_list[1:]       # для всех остальных
    result = result.merge(i, ...)
```